# Get NULL value in MYSQL for TIMEDATE

Tags: mysql, insert

When I insert the codes as is I get NULL

```
INSERT INTO dates VALUES (date='12-11-20 11:30:11');
```

When I fire query

```
SELECT * FROM dates;
```

I get

```
|dates |
| NULL |
```

Comment: Change the value format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: learn the insertion query google it

Comment: is `VALUES (date='...')` actually valid syntax in MySQL?

Comment: It is. ) Any valid expression may be the VALUES param. And this (if `date` column exists in the table altered) is a valid expression, amazingly. )

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO dates (date) VALUES('12-11-20 11:30:11')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong.

Correct syntax is as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO dates (dates) VALUES ('12-11-20 11:30:11');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `INSERT` query is wrong. Use one of the following syntaxes:

```
INSERT INTO dates (date) VALUES ('12-11-20 11:30:11')
INSERT INTO dates SET date = '12-11-20 11:30:11'
```

The first one is preferred since that works in all databases while the latter is most likely not standard SQL.

You should also consider to use `2012-11-20` instead of `12-11-20`. We all know what happened 12 years ago due to people not using 4-digit years.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several interesting issues to note here.

First, it's safer in my opinion to explicitly state the fields which will be updated: otherwise the query becomes unusable after the table's structure changes. And it's not recommended to give the same name to the table's field and the table itself: it may confuse you later.

Second, your DATETIME literal is actually ok for MySQL - it accepts two numbers for a year, parsing it by a specific rule:

```
Year values in the range 70-99 are converted to 1970-1999.
Year values in the range 00-69 are converted to 2000-2069.
```

So you may still use '12-11-20' syntax... if, again, it won't become confusing to whoever will maintain your script later (even you, perhaps.. )).

Finally, INSERT expression can take any valid expression within the VALUES clause. In your case it's `date = '...'` expression, which is evaluated to NULL; that's why NULL gets inserted in your table. If you, however, want to insert only the DATETIME literal (and you probably do), drop the assignment sign (which is actually taken as 'equality operator') and use simply...

```
 INSERT INTO dates (datetime_field) VALUES ('2012-11-20 12:12:12');
```

... or this, if you want to insert several rows with a single query:

```
 INSERT INTO dates (datetime_field) VALUES ('2012-11-20 12:12:12'), ('2012-11-20 13:13:13');
```

Hope this helps. ) But even if you don't have any questions, I'd still recommend studying [Insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and [Date and time literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html) topics anyway - it WILL be helpful.